# kafka-connect SSL error when using plaintext

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.confluent.io/4.0.0/installation/docker/docs/tutorials/connect-avro-jdbc.html

and put my code here: https://github.com/lexsteens/kafka-connect-tutorial

I have a problem when I'm registering the JDBC connector: it gets registered, but when looking its status in http://localhost:28083/connectors/quickstart-jdbc-source/status , I get a status FAILED, and the following stack trace:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: quickstart-jdbc-test
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:77)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:220)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:161)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:218)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:307)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:299)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:294)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:61)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:100)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:79)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.serialize(AvroConverter.java:110)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:220)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, I didn't request SSL encryption (see my [docker-compose](https://github.com/lexsteens/kafka-connect-tutorial/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)...).

I tried to google this issue or find it here, but had no success.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, remove `localhost` entirely from your Compose file. I'm surprised services will start correctly. Review [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and learn that setting the `hostname` property is not required and you can link service using just the "service name". For example, kafka would connect to `zookeeper:32181`, not localhost, and you Connector JSON should connect to `mysql:3306` address, not `localhost:3306`, etc.

You can look at my [compose file for reference](https://github.com/cricket007/kafka-connect-sandbox/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml), which is partitially taken from [Confluent's Docker Compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/master/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml).

While I've only tested with S3 Connect so far, your problem is coming from the `AvroConverter`, which is shared over all those projects, and I can verify that it did work for writing Avro messages to S3.

Specifically regarding the errors, they are related to the Schema Registry, and your Connect service has an HTTPS address to it, but doesn't look like you set up SSL for that container

Btw,  my suggestion would be to try at least `4.1.2` images rather than 4.0.0 to get the latest patches. if not, the latest is currently `5.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Actually, the problem was that I put https in the schemaregistry urls. After correcting that it worked.

I unfortunatelly never saw that even after reading myself 5x, I asked another pair of eyes and it was spotted right away :)